# Sequelize - Nested include (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

**I'm having three tables X,Y,Z**

```
       X.hasMany(Y)
       Y.belongsTo(X)
     Y.hasMany(Z)
        Z.belongsTo(Y)

       db.organisation.hasMany(db.application);
      db.application.belongsTo(db.organisation);

      db.application.hasMany(db.member)
     db.member.belongsTo(db.application)
```

Means Y having fK of X  and Z having fk of Y

How to get all three tables realted data's ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here it is in documentation: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#multiple-eager-loading